# bash + how to combine output values in the same line

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk, sed

we have two array variables:

linux_machines

disks

```
printf "%s\n" ${linux_machines[*]}

neptun1
neptun2
neptun3

printf "%d\n" ${disks_num[*]} 

4
5
5
```

how to combine both arrays values so w'll get the following expected results

```
neptun1 ..... 4
neptun2 ..... 5
neptun3 ..... 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`paste`** + **`printf`** solution:

```
linux_machines=("neptun1" "neptun2" "neptun3")
disks=(4 5 5)
paste -d' ' <(printf "%s .....\n" "${linux_machines[@]}") <(printf "%d\n" "${disks[@]}")
```

The output:

```
neptun1 ..... 4
neptun2 ..... 5
neptun3 ..... 5
```

Answer (score 5):

With bash:

```
for i in ${!linux_machines[@]}; do echo "${linux_machines[$i]} ..... ${disks_num[$i]}"; done
```

Output:

```
neptun1 ..... 4
neptun2 ..... 5
neptun3 ..... 5
```

I assume that neither arrays has gaps in the field numbering.

Comment: i highly like that answer since it's achieve what the `OP` need in automatic way without manually insert .

Comment: This expects both arrays to have the same indexes though.

Answer (score 0):

Used below method to achieve the same.

---

```
for i in 0 1 2; do echo ${linux_machines[$i]]}" ...... "${disks[$i]}; done
```

---

output

```
neptun1......4
neptun2......5
neptun3......5
```

---